# Xcode 14.0 not building to iOS 16.3 device

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an iOS app targeting iOS 16.0 using Xcode 14.0. I can build and run the app using the Xcode simulator, but when I try to run the app on my device running on iOS 16.3 I get the following error message from Xcode:

> **The run destination [device name] is not valid for Running the scheme [app name]:** Failed to prepare the device for development. This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is incompatible with the installed version of Xcode. You may also need to restart your Mac and device in order to correctly detect compatibility.

I have tried restarting both my machine and device, cleaning build folders but nothing seams to work.

Is this an issue with Xcode 14.0 or iOS 16.3?

Comment: According to the release notes, you would need 14.3: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes

Comment: @jnpdx No, 14.3 is still in beta. Xcode 14.2 works with iOS 16.3.

Comment: Okay -- interesting. The release notes say 16.2

Comment: Yeah, normally the Xcode version aligns with the iOS version, but I think 14.3 wasn't ready so they updated 14.2 to work with 16.3

Comment: Yes, I updated Xcode to 14.2 and it worked fine although the release notes saying it only has the SDK for 16.2.

Answer (score 1):

As @jnpdx and @Paulw11 said, you have to update Xcode to version 14.2.

Although the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14_2-release-notes) says it has the SDK for iOS 16.2, it works on iOS 16.3 just fine.